# Looking for Brian tts voice/app for Windows 10

Tags: text-to-speech

I have spent quite a while trying to find an application with Brain text to speech (tts) voice. I would like to be able to type in an input and have it read out loud, just like "Type to voice chat" - a Microsoft app. I find it an inconvenience of having to have a browser open for text to speech purposes and I'd need to come with something to redirect the audio to an application.

Needed:
Brian tts voice
Must be an application

Wanted:
Can redirect audio

I only found few sites offering Brian tts voice. Some of them were offering to let me download an MP3 file of text being read. Some were online only.